# .serialize() dont show name of input in post if field is empty

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

There is one problem. I have `.serialize()`, and want dont show name of input in post if field is empty, to post was cleaner. But dont know how.

```html
<form id="profile-form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="Profile-twitter" type="text"  id="inputTwitter" placeholder="Twitter Link">
    <input name="Profile-youTube" type="text"  id="inputYouTube" placeholder="YouTube Link">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="Profile-submit">Profil aktualisieren</button>
</form>
```

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a current console.log

Comment: You can restrict printing to console if input field is empty simply by using an if else statement.

Comment: @Sivaprasad
OK I understood. Create a variable in which the value will be saved, and its condition for comparison. But I vyrizal only a part of the whole form, there are many inputs, and I will have to create a very large comparison. what is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common solution to your problem is to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on `serilizeArray()` of your form,

whether you use `serialize()` or `serilizeArray()` it doesn't make any difference to post, you will get same **post variable in both the case**, here we use `serilizeArray()`.

@sivaprasad's answer will work for **input only** (i know that questioner also want solution for input only),

but you can do it with **simple** and short method with **less code** using `javascript`'s **inbuilt function** `filter()`.

See below for **simpler solution** which **also works for all form elements** (input, textarea, checkbox, radiobutton etc):

```js
//JAVASCRIPT or <script> tag

$("form").on("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   let filteredArray = $('#profile-form').serializeArray().filter(function (k) {
      return $.trim(k.value);
   });
   console.log(filteredArray);
});
```

```css
/*** CSS ***/

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML FORM -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="profile-form" method="post" action="submit_using_jQuery.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputTwitter">Twitter Link</label>
        <input name="Profile-twitter" type="text"  id="inputTwitter" placeholder="Twitter Link">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputYouTube">YouTube Link</label>
        <input name="Profile-youTube" type="text"  id="inputYouTube" placeholder="YouTube Link"><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bio">Bio</label>
        <textarea name="Profile-bio" id="bio"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Gender</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Profile-gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="Profile-gender" value="female">Female
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Hobby</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Profile-hobby[cricket]">Cricket
        <input type="checkbox" name="Profile-hobby[football]">football
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="Profile-submit">Profil aktualisieren</button>
</form>
```

Here is short and sober **javascript(ES6) arrow function** for **filtering serializeArray()**:

```
let filteredArray = $('#profile-form').serializeArray().filter(k => $.trim(k.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var flag = false;
        //if($("#inputTwitter").val() != "" && $("#inputYouTube").val() != "")
        $(this).find(">div>input").each(function(index, el){
            if ($(el).val().length == 0) 
                flag = true; 
        });
        if( !flag )
            console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
    });
```

Comment: In the comments I have already described the part. I need a case that is not tied to a specific input or their number. Since at the moment I have 66 inputs.

Comment: @ИванЗавалинич  check the new update. it might help i think, no matter how many input fields you have

Comment: I see.But can you do it somehow by the class name, since there is a different amount of nesting in the form. (form-control, this is the only thing they have in common)

Comment: @ИванЗавалинич Change  $(this).find(">div>input").each(function(index, el){  as $(".form-group").find(">input").each(function(index, el){. (I hope this is what you asked.)

Comment: error (Comparison $(el).val().length == '' may cause unexpected type coercion )

Comment: can you explain the scenario of getting this error. I can't figure it out because it is working fine for me for the html code you have given.